# compgen warning: -C option not working as I expected

Tags: bash, autocomplete, compgen

What is the correct way to use the `compgen -C` option?

I'm trying to learn about Bash programmable completion, and in particular the `compgen` builtin function. I'm experimenting with the different `compgen` command-line options, and I don't understand how the `-C` flag is supposed to work. From the [GNU Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html):

> -C command
>
> > command is executed in a subshell environment, and its output is used as the possible completions.

Based on this, I expect something like the following to work:

```
$ compgen -C 'echo "first_option second_option"' f
first_option
```

But instead, I get this:

```
$ compgen -C 'echo "first_option second_option"' f
-bash: compgen: warning: -C option may not work as you expect
first_option second_option  f
```

I've tried this with Bash version 4.2.45 on OS X 10.7 and with Bash version 4.2.25 on Ubuntu 12.04, and in both cases I get the same error:

```
-bash: compgen: warning: -C option may not work as you expect
```

Answer (score 4):

Referring again to the bash manual page:

> When using the -F or -C options, the
> various shell  variables  set  by  the  programmable  completion
> facilities, while available, will not have useful values.

I assume this is the "unexpected behaviour" it's referring to.  The lack of `$COMP_WORDS` and `$COMP_CWORD` in the subshell created by compgen mean that your initial "f" doesn't get passed in to filter the results, hence the first two options you see.  The third "f" -- I'll get on to.

It's even more unexpected at first glance that there seems to be no way to suppress this output (apart from piping away stderr) - but in fact there's a reasonable explanation.  The arguments are intended to be used against the `complete` command, with which `compgen` shares code and arguments, and where they make more sense.

The `complete` command is used in the registration of a completion command, e.g.

`complete -C /tmp/test.sh mycmd`

And the bash [source](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/) (in `pcompletion`, `gen_command_matches()` or thereabouts) explains how your "f" got into the results:

```
/* [...]
 $0 == cs->command         (command to execute for completion list)
 $1 == command name        (command being completed)
 $2 = word to be completed (possibly null)
 $3 = previous word
 [...] */
```

The third result in your example is of course your command input being passed back out as argument `$2`.  Using the completion spec we created above, we can show more clearly how it's meant to be used with a script which annotates the arguments:

```
 $ cat > /tmp/test.sh << EOF
 x=0
 for arg in $0 $@; do⋅
   echo "$x:$arg"; x=$[$x+1]
 done
 EOF
```

then:

```
 $ complete -C /tmp/test.sh mycmd
 $ mycmd prevarg curarg<tab><tab>
 0:/tmp/test.sh   1:mycmd   2:curarg   3:prevarg
```

So it's not to say that `-C` can't be used by compgen; just that you're no better off than with `$()`.

I suppose the remaining question is, "why are -C and -F defined against compgen at all?".  I don't know.

### Update

This answer originally contained my supposition

> [Leaving -C and -F defined was] easier, maybe; or perhaps the authors decided a (rather
> obscure) warning was better than simply disabling what could be useful functionality.

alongside a suggestion to

> make a [bug report](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Reporting-Bugs.html) seeking clarification and/or improved documentation from the authors...

And I'm thrilled to say there *was* an authoritative answer courtesy of Chet Ramey basically confirming this.  Quoting the [bash-bug mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/r/bug-bash/2014-04/msg00102.html):

> The command has total freedom to come up with possible completions;
> the completions don't even have to share a common prefix -- the
> higher-level completion code in readline takes care of that.  Shell
> functions specified with -F work the same way.
>
> The rationale is that it allows you to use binaries or scripts written
> in other languages in the same way you would use shell functions to
> generate programmable completions.
>
> It's not very useful to call this at the command prompt, since much of
> the readline context is not present.

Comment: This answer has solved me more questions than all the `complete` _"tutorials"_ I've been able to see so far. Thanks!

Comment: @JorgeBellón I'm really glad you found it useful, I wrote a lot of completion code for local tools back then and took me a while to dig some of this info up, so I'm pleased to have been able to share it. That said, I probably should have also shared my insight with the bash maintainers...